# ASP and jQuery Email Form not sending textarea

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, email, form-submit

Everything is working perfectly except it isn't sending the "OtherText" value of the textarea.

HTML:

```
<label for="ReasonforRMA">Reason for RMA:</label>
<select name="ReasonforRMA" class="required" id="otherCheck">
<option value="">Choose an option</option> 
<option value="Wrong Item">Wrong Item</option>
<option value="Defective">Defective</option>
<option value="Unit Damaged">Unit Damaged</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br />

<label for="OtherText" id="otherLabel">Other Reason:</label>
<textarea name="OtherText" id="otherText"></textarea><br />
```

jQuery:

```
var textarea = $('#otherText');
var textlabel = $('#otherLabel');
textarea.hide();
textlabel.hide();

$('#otherCheck').change(function(){
        var select   = $(this).val();
        if (select == 'Other'){
          textlabel.show();
          textarea.show();
        }
        else {
          textlabel.hide();
          textarea.hide();
        }
});
```

ASP:

```
<%
'declare variables
Dim EmailFrom
Dim EmailTo
Dim Subject
Dim DealerName
Dim DealerNumber
Dim InvoiceNumber
Dim PONumber
Dim InvoiceDate
Dim ModelNumber
Dim SerialNumber
Dim ReasonforRMA
Dim OtherText
Dim ConditionofUnit

' get posted data into variables
EmailFrom = Trim(Request.Form("EmailFrom")) 
EmailTo = "myemail@email.com"
Subject = "Online RMA Submission"
DealerName = Trim(Request.Form("DealerName")) 
DealerNumber = Trim(Request.Form("DealerNumber")) 
InvoiceNumber = Trim(Request.Form("InvoiceNumber")) 
PONumber = Trim(Request.Form("PONumber")) 
InvoiceDate = Trim(Request.Form("InvoiceDate")) 
ModelNumber = Trim(Request.Form("ModelNumber")) 
SerialNumber = Trim(Request.Form("SerialNumber")) 
ReasonforRMA = Trim(Request.Form("ReasonforRMA")) 
OtherText = Trim(Request.Form("OtherText")) 
ConditionofUnit = Trim(Request.Form("ConditionofUnit"))

' prepare email body text
Dim Body
Body = Body & "Dealer Name: " & DealerName & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Dealer Number: " & DealerNumber & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Invoice Number: " & InvoiceNumber & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "PO Number: " & PONumber & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Invoice Date: " & InvoiceDate & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Model Number: " & ModelNumber & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Serial Number: " & SerialNumber & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Reason for RMA: " & ReasonforRMA & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Other Text: " & OtherText & VbCrLf
Body = Body & "Condition of Unit: " & ConditionofUnit & VbCrLf

' send email 
Dim mail
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail") 
mail.To = EmailTo
mail.From = EmailFrom
mail.Subject = Subject
mail.Body = Body
mail.Send 

' send confirmation
Dim mailC
Set mailC = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
mailC.To = EmailFrom
mailC.From = "ouremail@email.com"
mailC.Subject = "Confirmation of your RMA Submission"
mailC.Body = "Test Confirmation"
mailC.Send

' redirect to success page 
Response.Redirect("complete.html")
%>
```

It's sending everything but the "OtherText" textarea value.. I am guessing it just a typo or something somewhere but I can't see anything!!

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but as a matter of good coding, you should using the EXACT same string for `name` and `id` on those form HTML fields. It will avoid potential confusion.

Comment: I guess it was?? I changed all my IDs to follow the same naming scheme and it works now.. thanks lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of good coding, you should using the EXACT same string for name and id on those form HTML fields. It will avoid potential confusion.

It's possible that ASP, for reasons all its own, is (incorrectly) using the ID attribute as the variable name instead of the name attribute.